# Converting a double to a float?

Tags: floating-point, double, precision

I have a list of 100k stars each are plotted using doubles an example:

Coordinates of a star [32.381562, 124.628052, -354.710990]

I'm working with unity and large scales so I need to be able to convert these doubles to floats, is there any method available without losing critical precision?

Comment: Can you provide more context? Are you programming in a particular language? Which one? When you say you have a "list of 100k stars", are you talking about a file on disk containing coordinates? Or an object in some programming language (again, which one?) What do you mean by "large scales"?

Comment: I will be coding in c# and java, file on a disk containing co-ordinates

Comment: Why do you want to work in float rather than double? The usual case for float is that you don't need double's precision and range, and are short of memory. You do need precision and range. 300 K doubles takes 2.4 MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure this is what you want to do, the standard way to convert from a double to a float is:

```
float someFloat = 32.381562;
double someDouble = (double) someFloat;
```

It's called casting or type conversion, and you can read all about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).